# 1. go onstage 2. go on stage 3. go on the stage (any difference could be?)

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

> 1. go onstage 2. go on stage 3. go on the stage (any difference could be?)

a dictionary says 'go on the stage' means 'become an actor' if so, what's the meaning of 'go onstage' and if I omit the article 'the' as like 'go on stage', does this have the same meaning as 'go on the stage'?

If I intend to express 'physically, really now go onto the stage', can I say 'someone is going onstage now' or'someone is going on the stage now' or 'someone is going on stage now(without the article 'the')'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- to **go on stage, to go on the stage** are idioms for acting in the theatre, but not for movie acting really.

That said, stage lingo can get complicated.

He went on the stage instead of sitting in a seat like most directors. [physical]

Actors can be said to come on stage when performing. They are also said to go on.

"When did you go on [the stage or stage] tonight? Did you go on at 8 or 9?"

the word stage is often omitted when referring to a stage performance.

He came on [the stage] stage left.
He came on [the stage] stage right.
She entered stage right.
She entered stage left.

come on or enter **the stage** from the wings. [the is needed]

The technician went on (the) stage to adjust the electric candlelight.

The technician did not go on (the) stage from the wings. He jumped up onto it.

All of the above mean physically going onto a stage.

**onstage** is an adjective: We had loads of issues with the onstage floor lights.

Comment: Thx. 'onstage' can also act as an 'adverb' http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=onstage&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=000

Comment: Actually, I would say it is used as a noun there.